# Using normal vs inline images in emails

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments

Can anyone comments on the ups/downsides of using inline attachments in emails for small graphic elements VS having them be links to online resources ?

We would prefer not to have users be forced to click 'Display images' (which seems to work well for gmail)

But are there other clients that might fail ?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience i do not use inline attachments for any images in emails i create. The reasoning is that many spam filters will increase the spam rating for your message and possibly place it in the junk folder. Also some clients will not show the embedded images at all, and just show alt text and an outline, or even nothing at all.

Depending on your email i would use online images and perhaps add a message asking them to add you to their contacts (e.g show images by default).

More reading:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/design-guidelines/

p.s I dont work for campaignmonitor i just use their resources :)